# Использование стека вызова функций в Dart для сохранения переменных double и int

Tags: функции, dart, стек, локальные-переменные

Если в java, int и double - это элементарные типы, то в Dart это классы. Заметил, что в Dart при вызове функций, аргументы (переменные-объекты) типа int и double ведут себя так же как в Java, т.е. передаются по значению. Как объяснить такое поведение, ведь в данном случае переменные int и double-это объекты, и, мне кажется, было бы логично, если бы по значению передавались только ссылки на объекты.
Где сохраняется в Dart содержимое локальных переменных int и double: в стеке или в куче? И за счет каких механизмов поддерживается логика работы с переменными int и double в DART? Кажется, что похожая логика работы реализована и в Kotlin...

Answer (score 1):

Тут все дело в том, что int, double, String, boolean, null - это литералы (каноничные объекты) из коробки.

Поэтому при одинаковых значениях это буквально ссылка на один и тот же объект:

```
void main() {
  print(identical(1, 1)); // true
  print(identical('a', 'a')); // true
  print(identical(true, true)); // true
}
```

И сам объект является неизменяемым (immutable).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).